# Excel - Formula to see if IP address is contained within list of subnets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ip

I am trying to create a formula, where i compare a list of IP addresses with a list of subnets. Let's say IP addresses (hosts) in column A and Subnets in Column B, with a CIDR format (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24)

How do I compare each IP to the list of subnets, so that the formula returns "TRUE" if the subnet contains at least one IP in column A, and "FALSE" if the subnet doesn't contain any IP?

My objective, trivially, is to find out if such subnets have active hosts (Column A) in them or not.

I found an Excel macro which contians many functions for manipulation of IP addresses (link removed for security purposes), however there don't seem to be any functions in it which are useful to my cause.

Below is an image,as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, a check on the subnet is made for each IP address, in order to verify if the subnet is used by at least one host or not:
[image: Example]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't post links to macro-enabled workbooks. Post the code in a code block instead.

Comment: Removed the link, sorry

Comment: ok, but you should add either the code you're using and, if possible, a screenshot of the source data

Comment: Thanks Lambik, I have added a screenshot of the data (anonymized) with an explanation of what the output should look like. At the moment I didn't come up with a finalized formula/code. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I would take a loot at this github.

A ton of answers about VBA IP Functions.

https://github.com/andreafortuna/VBAIPFunctions/blob/master/IPFunctions.vba

Comment: Hello IrwinAllen13, thanks for your response. The IpSubnetVLookup function does exactly what I'm asking: it compares an IP address with a list of subnets, and returns the subnet which uses the IP address. By using this list of subnets, I can filter out the remaining ones. Thanks a lot.